# Index does not receive shadow root events in polymer

Tags: events, polymer, shadow, listeners

I try to display a toolbar which belongs to my index.html file, based on an event which is fired within a custom element. I've tried to follow the example given in the official doc here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events

But it does not work...it seems my listener never gets the event

my custom element:

```
<dom-module id="page2">
    <template>
     ...
     some HTML code here
     ...
     </template>

     <script>

     Polymer({
        is: 'page2',

        rowClicked: function (e) {
                this.fire('displayMenu');
            }
     });
     </script>

</dom-module>
```

and in my index:

```
<page2></page2>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {

    document.querySelector('page2').addEventListener('displayMenu', function () {
        console.log('foo');
    });


});
    </script>
</body>
```

So yeah, nothing happens, I never get "foo" in my console...

Comment: have you tried with lowercase-only names like `display-menu`?

Comment: Event names don't have format requirements. The name could even be `"display menu"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS looks correct, but the element name is wrong. As indicated in Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#register-element):

> By specification, the custom element's name **must contain a dash (-)**.

So, `"page2"` would fail registration with the following error ([demo](http://jsbin.com/negaco/edit?html,console,output)):

> "Error: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'page2'. The type name is invalid.

If you rename the element to include a dash (e.g., **"x-page2"**), you should see your example work:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-page2></x-page2>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      document.querySelector('x-page2').addEventListener('displayMenu', function() {
        console.log('foo');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <dom-module id="x-page2">
    <template>
      <button on-click="rowClicked">click me to fire event</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-page2',
          rowClicked: function() {
            this.fire('displayMenu');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bicefo/edit?html,console,output)</sup>

Comment: Ho well, thanks, but that's not the problem: in my real code, the element registration contains a dash. I just quickly edited it to not publish my company code. Thanks anyway for taking the time to answer me, and to remind me this rule zhich I must admit i forgot about :)

But yeah... I still don't get why it doesn't work...

Comment: It might help to show the contents of the element's template.

Comment: Ok found the bug. Actually it was because I had some script before, in my index.html which contained an (unrelated) error. therefore the part of the script I wrote here wasn't executed. Sorry, but thank you for your time and for reminding me the dash registration rule :)